# execute several queries in one variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have in a variable DDL and DML queries.

example:

```
 var1='insert into tb1 (id) values(1); insert into tb1 (id) values(2); insert into tb1 (id) values(3);'
```

I want to execute the var1 that contains several inserts.
how to do that? execute immediate didnt worked.

Edit:
I tryd this , It didnt work because there is ';' inside it.

```
 DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
 BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into ex_employee (id) values (3); insert into ex_employee (id) values (4);');
 END;
 /
```

Comment: You need to frame it as a [dynamic PL/SQL block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS633).

Comment: I made a slight change to your version. Kindly check the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed your Inserts into a `BEGIN-END` anonymous block like one below.

[Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS633_)

```
DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
 BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN insert into ex_employee (id) values (3); insert into ex_employee (id) values (4); END;';
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --Handle Exception here.
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Yes, same like a Normal PL/SQL. Exception inside the dynamic execution, would be thrown to the Executor block itself.

Comment: ah tahts great , another question IF it was several blocks example: execute immediate 'begin ... end; begin ... end;' would it work ?

Comment: No,instead you can again nest the begin-end; like `begin-begin-end;begin-end;end;` So, it looks like only `BEGIN-END`